# Python couldn't make conditional class?

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements

```
class someclass:
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha
    if self.alpha == 0 :
        def first(self) :
            print (self.alpha)
    else :
        def second(self):
            print ('nothing')
```

I want make some class like this.
Even in my opinion this code looks ridiculous.
I want to know this is possible or not. please give me any suggestion. thanks.

Comment: is the `if/else` block supposed to be within the init?

Comment: This makes no sense. For one thing you don't know what value `alpha` has during class definition, because it's only going to be provided when an instance is created. Also this makes your class incredibly difficult to use - if I'm given an instance of it, how do I know which method is available to call? Why not a single method that does e.g. `print(self.alpha if self.alpha == 0 else 'nothing')`? Take a step back - what's the _context_ here, why do you need this and how would you use it?

Comment: A1. if/else block is not in init.

Comment: A2 @jonrsharpe I'm studying python and I just make for fun and curiosity.

Comment: A3. @SembeiNorimaki just curious. thanks for attention to my odd question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to dynamically add a method to your class depending on an initialization value.  There are a couple of ways to handle this.  The first is to use `setattr` within the `__init__`.

```py
def first(self):
    print(self.alpha)

def second(self):
    print('nothing')

class Someclass:
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha

        if self.alpha == 0:
            setattr(self, 'first', first)
        else:
            setattr(self, 'second', second)
```

This is a bit of an anit-pattern and will not work with linters.

Another option is to have different subclasses and use a factory pattern to instantiate the objects.

```py
class Someclass:
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha

class Firstclass(Someclass):
    def first(self):
        print(self.alpha)

class Secondclass(Someclass):
    def second(self):
        print('nothing')

def make_someclass(alpha):
    if alpha == 0:
        return Firstclass(alpha)
    else:
        return Secondclass(alpha)
```